# Manhwa/manhua where a women transmigrates into a game where she is the second female lead

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I need help finding a manhwa/manhua where a woman transmigrates into a game where she is the second female lead.

After finding out she became the second female lead (she transmigrates in the beginning as a child, I think), she thinks of ways to get out of the village and steer clear of her second female lead fate. And immediately remembers a witch in the forest, who helps her study herbs and potions to become a scientist(?), I think. And later takes the exam and passes.

The OG male lead is a kind blond. And the male lead right now, if I remember, is a black-haired guy. I think the second female lead had like brown hair, if memory serves.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. What colour was the main character's hair?

Comment: Also, if anyone correctly identifies the manhua you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: I think she had like brown hair if my memory recalls

Comment: Was this definitely a full-color webtoon, and not a black&white Japanese manga?

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly [*I Reincarnated as the Hero's Childhood Friend Who Was the Losing Love Interest, so I Changed Jobs to Alchemist*](https://myanimelist.net/manga/125845), a Japanese black and white manga.

> Laura, the childhood friend, has been completely forgotten! In the world of a game, Laura has been reincarnated as "**the losing heroine who is forgotten, despite confessing**." Instead, she'll aim to be an alchemist to escape that fate...
>
> However, when Laura meets Arnold, a person who should not be there, she realizes there are many differences between this world and that of her memories. This difference could even affect the future of her childhood friend, the hero!
>
> She will never be chained down by fate! A **different world reincarnation** story of a girl who never gives up!

[image]

The synopsis covers several of the main points. The main character reincarnated in another world as a child. She's the second female lead of an RPG - the one that stays behind in the Hero's village while he's off adventuring, and falls in love with one of his companions. The cover shows the female main character with brown hair; the hero (OG male lead) has blonde hair, the new male lead has black hair.

She recalls a "witch" living in a forest and goes to be her apprentice...

[image]

And, after several years, passes the exam. Which includes her wearing a lab coat, which makes her look like a stereotypical scientist.

[image]